# How do I change bootstrap table properties on refresh

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap-table by wenzhixin on Github it is this one

I want to change table settings from `clickToSelect: true` to  `clickToSelect: false`  on refresh

Here is my Code :

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <button id="refresh"> Refresh
  </button>
  <table id="table">
  </table>
<html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
                method: 'get',
                url:"http://139.199.18.128/Home/GetJSON2",
                clickToSelect: true,
                columns: [
                            { checkbox: true },
                            { field: "name", title: "lon"},
                            { field: "customID", title: "level"}
                         ]
                });

   $("#refresh").click(function () {

     $("#table").bootstrapTable("refresh",
                {

                });
   });

});

$("#table").bootstrapTable("refresh",
                {  method: 'post',
                   url: "myUrl",
                   clickToSelect: false
                });
```

I hope I can get a solution.
Thanks.

Comment: [bootstrap-table by wenzhixin](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/)  on Github it is this [one](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is the call with refreshOptions outside of refresh button handler ? Try like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        method: 'get',
        url: "http://139.199.18.128/Home/GetJSON2",
        clickToSelect: true,
        columns: [{
                checkbox: true
            },
            {
                field: "name",
                title: "lon"
            },
            {
                field: "customID",
                title: "level"
            }
        ]
    });

    $("#refresh").click(function() {

        $("#table").bootstrapTable("refreshOptions", {
            clickToSelect: false,
            // Other options you want to override
        });
    });

});
```

EDIT

If you want only to change clickToSelect field, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/edvejew5/

If you want to disable/enable the checkboxes, check this:
http://jsfiddle.net/j9h62fk6/ ( could be much cleaner, but it's a start)

Comment: I Tried The Table can refresh but still The row can't be selected when I click it. @BorisS

Comment: @Elijah please check EDIT